# How to use a superclass method using reflections C#

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-2.0, superclass

I have a bunch of classes that inherit from a single class. I'm using reflections to access the classes, since the ones that will be accessed will change in runtime.

But I am having some trouble when trying to invoke a method declared at superclass.

Here is my parent class:

```
public class ParentClass {

    public ParentClass (Type type) {

    }

    public string method0String () {
        return string;
    }

    public void method1Void (string) {

    }

}
```

Here is my child class:

```
public class ChildClass : ParentClass {

    public ParentClass () : base(typeof(ChildClass)) {

    }

}
```

Here is the abstract class code where I cast the methods:

```
Type childType = Type.GetType(className[i]);
ConstructorInfo childConstructor = childType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);

object childObject = null;
childObject = childConstructor.Invoke(childObject, new object[0]);

MethodInfo parentMethod0String = childType.GetMethod("method0String");
MethodInfo parentMethod1Void = childType.GetMethod("method1Void");

parentMethod1Void.Invoke(childObject, new object[]{argString});
object finalString = parentMethod0String.Invoke(childObject, new object[0]);
```

The MethodInfos are always null, which causes this error when I try to invoke them:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I haven't found anyway around this.

Basically, I just need to invoke a super method using the child as the dynamic object. How can I achieve this?

@Edit

After @nvoigt answer, my code looks like this:

```
Type childType = Type.GetType(className[i]);
object childObject = Activator.CreateInstance(childType);

Type parentType = Type.GetType("ParentClass");
MethodInfo parentMethod0String = parentType.GetMethod("method0String");
MethodInfo parentMethod1Void = parentType.GetMethod("method1Void");

parentMethod1Void.Invoke(childObject, new object[]{argString});
object finalString = parentMethod0String.Invoke(childObject, new object[0]);
```

And the error is a little different:

```
System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
```

Comment: What's the trouble you are having? Error message?

Comment: I'm editing to add more info right now. :D

Comment: GetConstructor takes a array with the constructor parameters, not the target object instance

Comment: @vc74 Yeah, I know. But for some reason it was null after invoking the constructor. I now changed to Activator.CreateInstance( ) to avoid junky code.

Comment: @eddie_cat the link above, with the answer being on using BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy did not work for me. Sorry.

Comment: did you checked the value of className[i]? Is it correct?I tested it by changing the className[i] to "ChildClass", and it works fine.

Comment: @T.Rahgooy Yeah, just checked it again and it is.

Comment: @T.Rahgooy Sorry, the new error description was wrong. It says the type is not valid, not that there is no reference.

Comment: replace the className[i] with "childClass" and check if it works or not

Comment: It did... But the problem is... The list of which classes are going to pass through these methods is variable. I can't call it hardcoded like this. Is it because of the array?

Comment: Actually, I will check manually all twenty classes and search for any that breaks the code.

Comment: The problem arises when one of those classes is not a child of the base class.

Comment: Oh boy... The problem is in the shell script that generates this classes!
Thank you @T.Rahgooy! Sorry for the inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
namespace StackOverFlowTest
{
  using System;

  class BaseClass
  {
    public int BaseClassMethod(int x)
    {
      return x * x;
    }
  }

  class DerivedClass : BaseClass
  {
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      var derivedType = typeof(DerivedClass);
      var baseType = typeof(BaseClass);

      var method = baseType.GetMethod("BaseClassMethod");

      var derivedInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(derivedType);

      var result = method.Invoke(derivedInstance, new object[] { 42 });

      Console.WriteLine(result);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I could do it like that, but there are several classes since they are autogenerated from an external database... I would really need something more automated. :/

Comment: What exactly do you need automated? You could easily automate this.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your answer. I actually tried your solution, but the problem is... 
    System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.

Comment: So what *do* you receive instead? What is your current code?